# Proper notation for Random Matrix and observation

Tags: random-variable, notation

My question is simple, but I could not find any references for this particular case.

When we have a random vector, we usually use $\boldsymbol{X}$ to denote the random vector and $\boldsymbol{x}$ to denote an observation of this random vector.

Now, when we use matrices, the usual notation for a matrix is a non-bold upper-case letter (e.g. $X$). In this case, what is the proper (or most usual) notation in order to distinguish the random matrix and the matrix of observations?

Comment: I think by "non-bold lower-case letter" you mean "non-bold upper-case letter" so I edited your question. If I'm wrong feel free to update it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @utobi. My mistake. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of an IID sample ${\bf X}_1, \ldots, {\bf X}_n$, where ${\bf X}_i$ is a $p\times 1$ random vector, to denote a random matrix of all samples I prefer to use the Blackboard bold typeface

$$
\mathbb{X} = [{\bf X}_1|\cdots |{\bf X}_n].
$$

Yes, this matrix has dimension $p\times n$ and not $n\times p$, but it has its advantages, at least in multivariate analysis. It is used also by others, e.g. Koch (2014) *Analysis of Multivariate and High-Dimensional Data*, ISBN: 9780521887939.

In the case of an observed sample ${\bf x}_1, \ldots, {\bf x}_n$, I use

$$
\mathbb{x} = [{\bf x}_1|\cdots |{\bf x}_n].
$$

If you use LaTeX, to produce lower-case letters in Blackboard bold typeface, e.g. $\mathbb{x}$, you'll have to use the `bbm` package.

Comment: Thanks @utobi. In my case,  the columns are independents, but not identically distributed. the notation $\mathbb{X}$ still applies? And more important (for me): It is an recognized and accepted notation in statistical journals?

Comment: It does work also for non identically cases, although I'm not sure how this is useful there. In mean, in multivariate analysis $\mathbb{X}$ is useful because, .e.g., I can express the sample average say as $\bar x = (1/n)\mathbb{X}^\top {\bf1}_n$. So journals do have very strict rules on this (e.g. Biometrika) others (say Bayesian Analysis) are not that strict. My advice is to check your journal instructions for this.